# How to force text to appear on the left side with new line?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<td>` with nested `<p>`.  When text exceeds max length it prints the remaining text on the new line from right to left.[image: That;s an example]

How do I fix this, so the new line would start printing from right to left?
Here is the code I have:

```css
.group {
  border: 2px solid #FFCC00;
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 32.85%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
}

.group article {
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.group article table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <article>
    <header> Links</header>
    <hr/>
    <section>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p><a href="example.com/" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>Description </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Just the new line, or all the text from left to right?

Comment: Djave, all text. Right now new line starts on the right side and pushes to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
text-align: right;
```

Will make text align to the right hand side, as per your example.

```css
.group {
  border: 2px solid #FFCC00;
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 32.85%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
}

.group article {
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.group article table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 7px;
}

td.right p{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <article>
    <header> Links</header>
    <hr/>
    <section>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p><a href="example.com/" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
              <p>Description lorem ipsum dollar sit amet</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```